# this.state with if else in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to this.state in begining of _app file in constructor funtion...

but page cant get state...

console.log response = null ,getting data , null

this.state always null before render...

but if I use : setstate in spite of this.state inside constructor... page loading with no problem like that but , the problem this time is page loading multi time cause of setstate..

How can I handle that.. any idea?

```
    import React                    from 'react'

import thunk                    from 'redux-thunk';
import logger                   from 'redux-logger';
import Mystore                  from '../store/store';

import { Provider }             from 'react-redux';
import { composeWithDevTools }  from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { compose,applyMiddleware,legacy_createStore as createStore} from 'redux';

import AuthControl              from '../Middleware/AuthControl';

import MyLoading                from '../components/loading';
import Header                   from '../components/Main/header';
import Footer                   from '../components/Main/footer';

import Head                     from 'next/head';
import App                      from 'next/app'

import '../styles/globals.css';

export default class MyApp extends App {
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  const allEnhancers = compose(
    composeWithDevTools(
      applyMiddleware(thunk),
    )
  );
  var store   = createStore(Mystore,allEnhancers);
  this.state  = {store, onLine: null, Loginstatus: null, mobile:null, loading: true}; 
}

componentDidMount(){
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.addEventListener('online'  , this.handleOnlineChange,false);
    window.addEventListener('offline' , this.handleOnlineChange,false);
    window.addEventListener('resize',   this.handleResize,false);
    this.checkLog();
  }
}

async checkLog()  {
  const promt   = Promise.resolve(AuthControl());
  try {
    const value = await promt;
    this.setState((state, props)=> ({
      Loginstatus : value.data,
      mobile      : (window.innerWidth < 700),
      onLine      : window.navigator.onLine,
      loading     : (window.innerWidth < 175),
    }))
  } catch (err) {
      this.setState((state)=> ({
        Loginstatus : err,
        mobile      : true,
        onLine      : window.navigator.onLine,
        loading     : true,
      }))
  }
}

handleOnlineChange=()=>{
  this.setState((state)=> ({onLine:window.navigator.onLine}));
}

handleResize=() => {
  this.setState({
    mobile: window.innerWidth < 700,
    loading: window.innerHeight < 175
  })
};

componentWillUnmount(){
  window.removeEventListener('resize'  , handleResize,false);
  window.removeEventListener('online'  , handleOnlineChange,false);
  window.removeEventListener('offline' , handleOnlineChange,false);
}

render() {
const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

if(this.state == null  || !Component || !pageProps || !this.state.onLine || this.state.loading ){
return( 
  <>
  <Head>
  <title>Loading</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Generated by Imtaki" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  </Head>
  <MyLoading/>
  </>
)}
const {Loginstatus, mobile, store, loading}  = this.state;

console.log("aaa : ", this.state)

return( 
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Head>
    <title>Imtaki</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Generated by Imtaki" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </Head>
    <Header     logstatus={Loginstatus} winWidth={mobile}/>
    <Component  logstatus={Loginstatus} winWidth={mobile} {...pageProps} />
    <Footer     logstatus={Loginstatus} mobile={mobile} loc={"body"}/>
  </Provider>  
)
}}
```

Comment: When you say "page loading multi time" what do you mean? You mean your render method is called more than once? Is this actually causing a problem? P.S. you have some unnecessary code repetition and `this.setState` doesn't need to spread `...this.state`

Comment: I mean if I use  setstate inside constructor, this time console.log("123") called multi time in first load...

Comment: by the way which codes are repetition ?

Comment: Is one of your events firing straight away? RE repetition I may not have the logic exactly right but I mean something like this: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/Dy1hRABD

Comment: Ok I get what u mean.. thanks for advice about that... also do u have idea about my main problem?

Comment: Please add a CodeSandBox. You can try using `componentDidUpdate` to find out which state property update is causing the re-render.

Answer (score 2):

It is not advised to create a child class of a React Component. See https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html.

As @Dominic said, there's no need spread `this.state` inside `setState`. Not only it is unnecessary, but also can cause errors. Eg: you can do:

```
this.setState((state)=> ({
    mobile: (window.innerWidth <= 720 && !state.mobile)
});
```

When you need to update state using its previous value use the callback argument of `setState`. This prevents stale state values from being used. See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Keep the event listeners for `online` & `offline` in separate methods. Don't forget to use arrow functions or binding.

Do `addEventListener` inside `componentDidMount` & not directly inside the constructor. Also call `checkLog` inside `componentDidMount` only. Anything that needs the `window` object, should be out of the constructor.

Don't forget to call `removeEventListener` inside `componentWillUnmount` callback. Hence the need to store the listeners in separate methods.

Here's a sample:

```js
export default class MyApp extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      var store = createStore(Mystore,allEnhancers);
      this.state = {store, onLine: null, loginStatus: null, mobile:null, loading: null}; 
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.addEventListener('online'  , handleOnline);
      window.addEventListener('offline' , handleOffline);
      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
      checkLog();
    }
  }

  async checkLog()  {
    const allEnhancers = compose(
      composeWithDevTools(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
      )
    );
    const promt   = Promise.resolve(AuthControl());
    try {
      const value = await promt;
      this.setState((state)=> ({
        Loginstatus : value.data,
        mobile      : (window.innerWidth < 700),
        onLine      : window.navigator.onLine,
        loading     : (window.innerWidth < 175),
      }))
    } catch (err) {
        this.setState((state)=> ({
          store       : store,
          Loginstatus : err,
          mobile      : true,
          onLine      : window.navigator.onLine,
          loading     : true,
        }))
    }
  }

  handleResize=() => {
    this.setState({
      mobile: window.innerWidth < 700,
      loading: window.innerHeight < 175
    })
  };

  handleOnlineChange=()=>{
    this.setState((state)=> ({onLine:window.navigator.onLine}));
  }


  componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('resize'  , handleResize,false);
    window.removeEventListener('online'  , handleOnlineChange,false);
    window.removeEventListener('offline' , handleOnlineChange,false);
  }
}
```

Comment: first of all thx for your advices, all of them are valuable.. I update my code, as what u told... and but my main problem still continue... page load multi time at begins...

Comment: I edited the question with updated code...

Comment: thanks for kindly reply.. I reupdate the codes again with removelisteners and remove ...this.states

Comment: by the way.. I change resize code like my code cause otherwise eventlistener always render page wheneverchange the pagesize... in this code only render page when change 700px and 175 px

Comment: But even with that code.. on first load page reload twice... by the way my next.config has module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  swcMinify: true,
   trailingSlash: true,}

Comment: The 2nd argument of `addEventListener` is the event listener. `addEventListener` returns `undefined`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: I updated codes as what u said.. but still console.log("aaa", this.state) load multi times :((

Comment: I also edited question with new code

Comment: at last I found issue the problem for multi render is ===   async rewrites() { } inside next.config.js

Comment: this is not solution actually,, this is another problem and now I am searching for it.. you can check it with your self in next js.. I just create fresh nextjs and just write a rewrite inside next.config.js and bom , render twice